# Distributivity of Conjunction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having trouble with understanding how distributivity of conjunction applies in a problem where I must prove:
$$ \neg (a \wedge \neg b \vee \neg c) = \neg (a \vee \neg c) \vee b \wedge c$$

My proof so far goes

$$ \neg (a \wedge \neg b \vee \neg c)$$
$$ = \neg a \vee \neg (\neg b \vee \neg c)$$
$$ = \neg a \vee \neg \neg b \wedge \neg \neg c$$
$$ = \neg a \vee b \wedge c$$
$$ = (\neg a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)$$
$$ = \neg(a \vee \neg c) \vee b \wedge c$$

I am not sure if the step from the 4th to 5th line is correct. The distributivity property as I understand it is $ (x \wedge z) \vee (y \wedge z) = z \wedge (x \vee y)$. I feel like it shouldn't apply in this case because the situation I have in line 4 is more like $ (z \wedge x) \vee y$. Does the presence of the parentheses prevent me from using the distributive property or do they go away after I distribute the negative sign?

Comment: Your formula $a \land \lnot b \lor \lnot c$ is ambiguous: does it stand for $(a \land \lnot b) \lor \lnot c$ or $a \land (\lnot b \lor \lnot c)$? Analguous problem with $\lnot(a \lor \lnot c) \lor b \land c$.

Comment: There was a time when conjunction had higher operational precedence than disjunction.  That convention has been depreciated for so long that it is confusing to read.  Please bracket your conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distribution laws:

- Conjunction distributes over disjunction: $x\land (y\lor z)=(x\land y)\lor(x\land z)$
- Disjunction distributes over conjunction: $x\lor (y\land z)=(x\lor y)\land(x\lor z)$

Also recall that conjunction and disjunction are both commutative.

- $x\land (y\lor z)=(y\lor z)\land x=(y\land x)\lor(z\land x)=(x\land y)\lor(x\land z)$
- $x\lor (y\land z)=(y\land z)\lor x =$ et cetera

Comment: Right. I would also add that in general $a \lor (b \land c) \ne (a \lor b) \land c$; there seems to be a lot of ambiguity wrt precedence of operators in the OP's reasoning.